# Using Ajax & PHP on same page, appending full page content again and again

Tags: php, ajax

I want to use ajax and PHP on the same page. For that I have removed the `url` paramter of ajax. Now when I am typing in the textbox, it is giving me desired results but it is appending a new page with all the elements inside the `#check-username`. I don't know why it is appending new textbox. Please take a look at my code.

```
<?php
global $wpdb; 
if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {
  $query = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "'");
    ob_clean();
  if($query>0) {
    echo "<span style='color:red'> Sorry User already exists .</span>";
  }else{
    echo "<span style='color:green'> User available for Registration .</span>";
  }
}
?>

<span id="check-username"></span>
<label class="form-label" for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control"/>
                
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#username').on('input', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    data:'username='+$(this).val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#check-username").html(data);
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to add `exit;` after you've echoed the messages, or you will get all the HTML (like the input) in your response as well. That PHP code should also be first of all, before _any_ HTML output. If you have any output before the PHP, that will also be part of the response.

Comment: **Warning!** You're open to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)! Use [wpdb's prepare() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) instead of injecting variables directly into your queries. It's not just about security. If your data contains, for example, a single quote `'`, your query will break.

Comment: Writing `exit;` after the echo in php is working fine as I am typing in the textbox, but as I delete the all the alphbets of textbox then new textbox append again. Regarding you second suggetion my php is at the first potion only before html and jquery. Can you please suggest me some owrking code sir.

Comment: The `exit` should be placed last in the `if(!empty($_POST["username"]))` statement, before the closing `}`.

Comment: It is working when I place it just before `}`. Now while I am typing everything is working great. But as I delete all the alphabets from the inputbox then again all page content append. And when I again start typing it remove and everything works file. I want even if I empty inputbox, it should not append again.

Comment: Change `if (!empty($_POST["username"]))` to `if (isset($_POST["username"]))`. You can also check in your JS if the textbox is empty or not. If it is empty, don't make the Ajax request at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exit;` and using `isset` instead of `!empty`, solved all the problems. Thanks to @M. Eriksson

```html
<?php
global $wpdb; 
if(isset($_POST["username"])) {
  $query = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "'");
    ob_clean();
  if($query>0) {
    echo "<style>#username{border: 3px solid green;}</style>"; 
  }else{
    echo "<style>#username{border: 3px solid red;}</style>"; 
  }
exit;
}
?>

<span id="check-username"></span>
<label class="form-label" for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control"/>
                
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#username').on('input', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    data:'username='+$(this).val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#check-username").html(data);
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
});});
</script>
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding what and why.